# Hyperlink to xpath

Tags: html, xpath

I want to create a hyperlink to a specific location on a site that I cannot edit.  The location I want to link to does not have an id anywhere near it, so `<a href="http://example.com/page.html#location">` will not work.  Is there a way to replace #location with an xpath?

Comment: add `#location` with `jquery` or `javascript` to that element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put an XPath after the "#", or you could use a query part ("?"), but the real question is, who is expected to understand this URI format and what are they expected to do with it? If it's only something that your own code is expected to understand (e.g. your own in-page Javascript) then you can do anything you like, but if you expect someone to store this URL in a bookmark or print it on the side of a truck, then you're probably out of luck.

Comment: I tried # and ?, neither works.  I am trying to create a to a specific location on a page that is not mine.  I want a link that works like the standard #, but does not need to target an id

Comment: As far as I know the basic ID after "#" is the only kind of fragment identifier supported natively by browsers.

Comment: Thank you for giving me the "fragment identifier" term, and from what I can tell you are correct